# Random Tie breaking via Index in Excel

Tags: excel, random, indexing, counter

My work has a "Shame" counter. Whoever gains the most shames in a week has to buy the round for the office the following week. Currently, we use

```
=INDEX(B5:B14,MATCH(MAX(C5:C14),C5:C14,FALSE),)
```

to choose the name with the highest number against it. However in the event of a tie, the result defaults to the name nearest the top of the table, rather than picking at random.

I've tried using the RANDBETWEEN() function, however can't seem to get it to pick the max value at random.

The counter itself can be found here: [Shame Counter](https://mega.nz/#!PXY1kByC!LbdrLb5yeZm2aooaR4etLlhGzqgr5hRt-5I9SI6iuiQ)

Please can someone have a look and advise?

Comment: what is the key?

Comment: Ah I copied the wrong one! I've updated it, it should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to randomly choose between the ties:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C5:C14)/(C5:C14 = MAX(C5:C14)),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(C5:C14,MAX(C5:C14)))))
```

Comment: @Jalder please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.